# Use socket io in C++ for dynamic number of bytes

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to implement a simple client-server application where a client or the server can send a dynamic number of bytes in a single `write()` call.

For example, let's assume that the client sends a byte stream of 1500 bytes. And server reads every 1000 bytes.

```
int BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
...
read( iSockFD, cBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE );
```

I can use a loop and call read until its return value is `0`. But the client may have multiple `write()` calls in a loop (i.e. sending multiple messages).

My question is, will it affect the `read()` on the server side? Meaning, will two consecutive `write()` of 1000 bytes in the client side, be read by a single `read()` with 2000 bytes buffer size at the server side?

If that's the case, what are the recommended ways of implementing such a scenario? Should I use a separator for messages (using an encoding algorithm)?

I understand this more related to sockets itself rather than C++. But, your help and guidance are highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

The intention is to implement a simple middleware system to send different types of messages, where the messages will be encoded in binary before sending.

Comment: You have to use some protocol that will inform what number of bytes should be read by a server.

Comment: Still, will it guarantee that a one `write()` is triggers a one `read()` ?

Comment: Send the size ahead with a certain number of bytes and endianess (typically 4 bytes, and in network byte order).

Comment: It's sticky package problem. Using TCP, you need to implement your own way to pack and unpack data. It's could be a type-length-data packet.

Comment: *Still, will it guarantee that a one write() is triggers a one read()*
No.

Comment: *Still, will it guarantee that a one `write()` is triggers a one `read()`* If we're talking TCP (and with stream and socket being keywords that sounds very likely) practically nothing can guarantee one write == one read.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But whoever downvoted and marked for close, I would be glad to have a reason why this question qualifies for that.

Comment: The question's not unclear to me, so I can't comment on the closevotes, and the downvotes are probably connected. But this question, or ones very much like it, is asked frequently and probably too broad.  @S.M. roughly answered it in the first comment, you need to establish a communication protocol, and we can't really suggest much better without information about the data being sent.

Comment: (as updated in the question) I want to implement a simple middleware system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody can guarantee you that a write(x) will trigger a read(x) at the receiver side. If x is larger than your socket receive buffer, or if you call read() before the entire message has been received in the socket receive buffer, then read() will only return a fraction of the data and require you to issue a subsequent read() to get the rest.

The recommended way of doing this would be to define a message buffer of sufficient size. Every call to read() will return 1 or more bytes, which you keep enqueuing into the buffer. Now, once the buffer is larger than 4 bytes + the be32toh(integer) stored in the first 4 bytes of the buffer, you have to consume the integer plus the following x bytes from the beginning of the buffer (and process them further). This will allow you to nicely handle cases where read() contains the end of a previously unfinished packet and at the same time contains the beginning of the next (incomplete) packet.

Just make sure that every payload you transmit is prepended by a htobe32(length).

Comment: Why only the length is converted (regarding the endianness) ? Why not the payload ?

Comment: Because you didnt say what kind of payload you transmit! If you transmit Protobuf, you dont need to bother about endianness. If you transfer a char stream, you don't need either! If you transmit integers, you do!

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. My intention is to convert an object to binary and transmit. I think then I don't need to worry about it too. Right?